# Histogram does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to compile this but it does not work. Could you help me fix it?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
        
        \pgfplotsset{x=\linewidth/7,
            width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.9\textwidth,
            axis line style = ,
            ybar, 
            xlabel={Calificaci\'on},
            ylabel={Porcentaje ($\%$)},
            label style={font=\tiny},
            ymin=0,
            ytick=\empty,
            xtick=data,
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
            xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-\baselineskip},
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
            nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize},
            xtick align=inside
        }
        
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[bar width=22pt]
            \addplot[black,fill=blue] coordinates {
                (1, 6.110)
                (2, 11.370)
                (3, 27.145)
                (4, 34.174)
                (5, 21.201)
            };
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}

        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[bar width=22pt]
            \addplot[black,fill= blue] coordinates {
                (1, 5.616226)
                (2, 10.753453)
                (3, 27.145)
                (4, 34.889808)
                (5, 22.626271)
            };
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}

        \end{subfigure}
        
\end{document}
```

ERROR:

[image: Screenshot of the error log]

Comment: Quoting the error message(s)  you get usually akes it a lot easier to answer questions or giving uesful suggestions. Especially since you then don't necessarily have to compile the given code. Could you therefore, and especially since your description "it does not work" is only very vague,  please add this information to your question?

Comment: Some hints on what might be the reason: `subfigure` only works inside of `figure`, while `figure` itself can't work in a `standalone`  file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`figure` does not work inside `standalone` and you need to wrap `subfigure` inside `figure` environment (as `@Ieandriis` already pointed out). And you need to use `pgfplots` package ;)

Here you go:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
{
    \pgfplotsset{x=\linewidth/7,
    width=0.8\textwidth,height=0.9\textwidth,
    axis line style = ,
    ybar, 
    xlabel={Calificaci\'on},
    ylabel={Porcentaje ($\%$)},
    label style={font=\tiny},
    ymin=0,
    ytick=\empty,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-\baselineskip},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize},
    xtick align=inside,
}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[bar width=22pt]
    \addplot[black,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (1, 6.110)
        (2, 11.370)
        (3, 27.145)
        (4, 34.174)
        (5, 21.201)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[bar width=22pt]
    \addplot[black,fill= blue] coordinates {
        (1, 5.616226)
        (2, 10.753453)
        (3, 27.145)
        (4, 34.889808)
        (5, 22.626271)
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{subfigure}
}


  \end{figure*}



\end{document}
```

[image]